# How to Enable publisher actions Programatically using API?

Tags: metadata-api, publisher

Is there any way to enable publisher actions (Accessed manually through Setup->Customize->Chatter->Settings->Publisher Actions) while installing a package using API?

Can metadata API be used for that?

Or can it be enabled using some other API after the installation as Post install script?

If this can be done by metadata API any sample codes avaliable?

Answer (score 3):

It does not appear these settings are available via the Metadata API. Recently, Salesforce did start exposing [Settings](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_settings.htm) via the Metadata API, but having checked just now I don't yet see this one. So I'm afraid the answer is no on this. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The entire group of settings under App Setup > Customize > Chatter > Settings is not accessible, so you would need to manually enable Chatter, Approval Posts, Publisher Actions, etc. Still not available as of Winter '15.